# mvc 4 razor dynamic table cells

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello can you please help me

In my view I have this table:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayName("idOperation")</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayName("NameOperation")</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="Operation" class="sltStyle">
        @foreach (var item1 in ViewBag.Operations)
        {         
          <option>@item1.Id_Operation</option>           
        }
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Controller

```
public class testController : Controller
{
  private RendementEntities db = new RendementEntities();
  public ActionResult PartialViewDemo()
  {
    List<Operations> allOperations = db.Operations.ToList();
    return View(allOperations);
  }
  public ActionResult NomOperation(int idOperation)
  {
    IEnumerable<Operations> allOperations = db.Operations.ToList();
    var selectedOperationId = (from c in allOperations where c.Id_Operation == idOperation select c.Id_Operation).FirstOrDefault();
    var NameForId = (from a in allOperations where a.Id_Operation == selectedOperationId select a.Designation).FirstOrDefault();
    return PartialView("_OperationsPV" , NameForId);
  }
}
```

Is it possible when the user chooses the idOperation(onclick) the nameOperation is generated automatically ?

thank you

Comment: what do you mean with "is generated automatically"? What should be displayed where? Did you try anything so far?

Comment: Posible bt i am not clear about your controller. Please Give me your full code.

Comment: by generated automatically I mean when the user chooses IdOperation the next column which is NameOperation is displayed automatically

Comment: You can use javascript to handle the change event of the `<select>` an update the value, but where does the value come from? And you need to learn to use a view model and html helpers correctly since none of what you have shown here will work

Comment: Nothing in your code makes any sense at all. Can you please outline what you actually want to do here. It appears you want to display a dropdown showing the `Designation` property of all `operations` and be able post back the `Id_Operation` property of the selected `operation`